# MongoDB Geospatial - Find all near points (couples)

Tags: mongodb, geospatial

I've been wanting to find all nearby **couples**, who are in a radius of eachother lets say the radius is smaller than 15km. As i want to inform the users, who are at these locations, that they are close to eachother.
What is the most performant way of doing this. I think i'm going with MongoDB with geospatial indexes as this seems to be the best solution for my problem. But all the examples only speak of finding the nearest points with a given lat/long. I need to find all close couples, not of only one point. 
Should I ran over all the different coordinates and find close ones or is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think that it is possible to do this without one database query per couple.

Comment: How many datapoints do you have? If they are not that many, you could just compare all coordinates with every other coordinate point. If you have a lot of, you could first group points by coordinates and then match only those in the same group.